# How to fetch data from last offset in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka for fetching data and sinking in another database. What I want to know is if any data loss occurs in between my consumer going down, and the topic retention duration, how can I fetch it again from the last offset?

Comment: Are you using Kafka Connect?

Comment: In between what? If you skip to the end of the topic, there certainly will be records lost

Comment: @RobinMoffatt yes! I am using Kafka Connect

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am sinking data in Elasticsearch. I have set retention time as one hour in Kafka topic. If my sink connector gets down for 1 hour, is there any method to recover those lost data?

Comment: Only closed segments are deleted on the broker, so data sometimes exist longer than the retention time. Once they're gone, no there is not.